# jQuery Mobile Cache or Something Else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, caching

I'm fairly new to jQuery mobile and this issue has stumped me.

I edited my app to dynamically create the  items based on the sub-domain the user arrives on. It grabs the sub-domain, looks up the client record associated with that sub domain, and changes the page title and the apple-touch-icons.

Here is the code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<? if ( empty($clientDomain) ) { ?>
    <title>AAA takein</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); ?>apple-icon-57x57.jpg" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); ?>apple-icon-72x72.jpg" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); ?>apple-icon-114x114.jpg" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); ?>apple-icon-144x144.jpg" />
<? } else { ?>
<title><? echo( $_SESSION["rName"] ); ?></title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); echo($_SESSION["image"]); ?>" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); echo($_SESSION["image"]); ?>" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); echo($_SESSION["image"]); ?>" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<? echo( IMAGES ); echo($_SESSION["image"]); ?>" />
<? }; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo( CSSURL ); ?>themes/foodie.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo( CSSURL ); ?>foodie.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo( CSSURL ); ?>themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo( JQMOBILE ); ?>jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="<? echo( JQ1 ); ?>"></script>
<script src="<? echo( JQMOBILE ); ?>jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo( CSS ); ?>">
<script src="<? echo( JS ); ?>"></script>
```

When I view the page, it loads initially as expected. However, almost instantly it seems to reload the page (or maybe just the head items) with what I assume must be a cached page.

My page title changes to "ZZZ TakeIn" - which is a previous version of the page.

I have cleared the browser cache. I have turned off jQuery caching - though, if my understanding is correct in v 1.4.5 that is the default anyway.

I have tried various scripts to stop first page cache, but to no avail. It must be coming from a cached version somewhere because I've tried commenting out the  tags and it still comes up with the old version.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this issue? I'm seeing the same sort of thing. Everything within <head>....</head> remains the same when I navigate to another page on the same site. It only occurs with pages that load JQuery Mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use html meta tags or .htaccess to prevent caching.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#100_Prevent_Files_cached